# How can I use an asynchronous javascript function like fetch inside a FormDataConsumer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, react-admin

I need to use a fetch inside the FormDataConsumer tag but it seems FormDataConsumer does not support async functions. This code didn't work for me:

```
<FormDataConsumer>
{
    async ({ formData, scopedFormData, getSource, ...rest }) => {
        return await fetch('/api/v1/attributes/'+scopedFormData.single_attributes_label)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            //return JSON.stringify(data);
            resolve(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
        return JSON.stringify(scopedFormData);
    }
}
</FormDataConsumer>
```

I also checked this code and this one also didn't work:

```
async function getAttrItem(id) {
  return await fetch(`/api/v1/attributes/${id}`).then(response => response.json())
}
```

...

```
<FormDataConsumer>
{
    async ({ formData, scopedFormData, getSource, ...rest }) => {
        return await JSON.stringify(getAttrItem(scopedFormData.single_attributes_label));
    }
}
</FormDataConsumer>
```

But when I use this one, it works in the console:

```
<FormDataConsumer>
{
    ({ formData, scopedFormData, getSource, ...rest }) => {
        fetch('/api/v1/attributes/'+scopedFormData.single_attributes_label)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            //return JSON.stringify(data);
            resolve(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
        return JSON.stringify(scopedFormData);
    }
}
</FormDataConsumer>
```

Should I use this FormDataConsumer for filling an object and then inside the other FormDataConsumer check the object?

Comment: What version of react-admin are you using?

Comment: react-admin v2.9.9 was used in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was fixed with this code:

```
<FormDataConsumer>
    {
        ({ formData, scopedFormData, getSource, ...rest }) => {
            return scopedFormData && formData && "type" in formData && <ReferenceInput label="Attribute Label" source={getSource('single_attributes_label')} reference={`attributes`} filter={{ document_type: formData.type }}>
            <AutocompleteInput optionText="title" optionValue="id" />
            </ReferenceInput>
        }
    }
</FormDataConsumer>
<FormDataConsumer>
    {
        ({ formData, scopedFormData, getSource, ...rest }) => {
            return "type" in formData && "single_attributes_label" in scopedFormData && <AttribValue source={getSource('single_attributes_value')} reference={`attributes`} filter={{ document_type: formData.type, id: scopedFormData.single_attributes_label, method: "getOptions" }} attribute={scopedFormData.single_attributes_label} {...rest} />
        }
    }
</FormDataConsumer>

const AttribValue = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  console.log('props', props);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/v1/attributes/" + props.attribute)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData({ data });
      });
  }, [props.attribute, props.label]);

  if (!data) {
    return 'Please Wait...';
  }
  let newProp = Object.assign({}, props, { label: "Attributes Value" });
  return data.data.attribute_type == 'multiselect' ? <ReferenceArrayInput {...newProp}><AutocompleteArrayInput optionText="text" optionValue="id" /></ReferenceArrayInput> : <ReferenceInput {...newProp}><AutocompleteInput optionText="text" optionValue="id" /></ReferenceInput>;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna do something like this:

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/v1/attributes/" + props.attribute)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data);
      });
  }, [props.attribute]);

  if (!data) {
    return <someloadingindicator />;
  }

  // now you got your data. you can now return some component that uses the data here
};


// now in your component where using the FormDataConsumer
<FormDataConsumer>
  {({ formData, scopedFormData, getSource, ...rest }) => {
    return <MyComponent attribute={scopedFormData.single_attributes_label} />;
  }}
</FormDataConsumer>;
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can run JavaScript expressions in JSX, it is not a good pattern to bloat it with too much JavaScript logic within JSX. The above logic should be handled within the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook for class components, or in the `useEffect` hook, for functional components.

In your `FormDataConsumer`

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/api/v1/attributes/'+scopedFormData.single_attributes_label)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
       // do the rest here
    });
}
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/api/v1/attributes/'+scopedFormData.single_attributes_label)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
       console.log(data);
       // do the rest here
    });
 }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about componentDidUpdate but I didn't want to use that. In somehow, using `useEffect` was my question.

Comment: @MasoudILDEREMI sorry, I mean `componentDidMount`, not `componentDidUpdate`.