# React useEffect infinite loop fetch data axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, infinite-loop, use-effect

I'm getting an infinite loop with this code.

I've been trying some of the solutions from another posts but they don't work.

`locationAddress` is an array of addresses and I'm trying to get the coordinates using the Google Maps Geocode API.

```
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'add':
                return [
                    ...state,
                    {
                        address: action.address,
                        name: action.name,
                        id: action.id
                    }
                ];
            case 'remove':
                return state.filter((_, index) => index !== action.index)
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    const [locationAddress, setLocationAddress] = useReducer(reducer, []);

    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchLocation = async () => {
            for(let i = 0; i < locationAddress.length; i++) {
                const response = await axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
                    params: {
                        address: locationAddress[i].address,
                        key: 'MyAPIKey'
                    }

                })
                .then(response => {
                        setLocationAddress({locationAddress: response.data});
                        setCoordinates([...coordinates, {lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng}]);
                        }
                    )
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }
        }
        fetchLocation();
    },[coordinates, locationAddress]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use an asynchronous javascript function like fetch inside a FormDataConsumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528291/how-can-i-use-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-like-fetch-inside-a-formdataco)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason behind that is your dependency array. Basically when `axios` call finished you are updating your dependencies with `setCoordinates` and `setLocationAddress` which triggers again the `useEffect` hook's callback.

If you replace `[coordinates, locationAddress]` with the setter functions [`setCoordinates`, `setLocationAddress`] then it will work as expected.

The solution which should work:

```
const [locationAddress, setLocationAddress] = useReducer(reducer, []);
const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    // ... removed definition for better representation in the answer

    fetchLocation();
}, [setCoordinates, setLocationAddress]);
```

You might have a warning message because of missing `coordinates` and `locationAddress` which you can disable with `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` comment one line before the dependency array.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

You are interating over the `locationAddress` array, calling the api and changing the same array inside the loop. This is causing the infinite loop. Why do you need to set the location address again? If you receive more information, put it in another array.